# reading from a file - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, unix, segmentation-fault

I have a big problem with this error. I tried in every way I knew to read from the file(fscanf, fgets, gets, fgetln, fread, read) but I couldn't manage it. Every time I get segmentation fault(core dumped) error). What do I have to do to print my file content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define MAX_COMAND_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARAMS 10

int i=0;

char cmd[MAX_COMAND_LENGTH+1];
char *params[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARAMS+1];

char cmdline[1000];
int hfd=-1,ifd=-1,ofd=-1;
int lines_in_hist = 0;
int curent_line = -1;

struct termios save_term;

char *HISTORY;

char *TEMP,*TEMP2,*ax;

void parseCmd(char *cmd, char **params)
{
    for(i=0; i< MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARAMS;i++){
        params[i]=strsep(&cmd," ");
        if(params[i] == NULL)
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char *username = getenv("USER");
     int status=-1;//pentru deschiderea fisierelor
     int status1;
     char *directory="/tmp";
     char *file_name;
     char buff[256];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("%s@shell >>", username);

        //citeste de pe linia de comanda
        if(fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin)==NULL)
            break;

        //elimina terminatorul de sir de pe o linie noua
        if(cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]=='\n')
            cmd[strlen(cmd)-1]='\0';

         parseCmd(cmd,params);

         if(!strcmp(params[0],"exit"))
            exit(0);

         if(!strcmp(params[0],"help"))
            help();

         if(!strcmp(params[0],"version"))
            version();


        if(!strcmp(params[0],"info"))
            if(!strcmp(params[1],"tail"))
                infoTail();
            else if(!strcmp(params[1],"uniq"))
                infoUniq();
            else if(!strcmp(params[1],"cd"))
                infoCd();

        if(!strcmp(params[0],"uniq"))
        {
            if(!strcmp(params[1],"-d"))
            {
                printf("Enter the name of file\n");
                gets(file_name);

                if((status=open(file_name,O_RDONLY))==-1)
                {
                    printf("Nu am putut deschide fisierul!");
                    exit(1);
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf("\t\t ==>%s<==\n",file_name); 
                    sscanf(file_name,"%s",buff);
                    printf("Continutul fisierului:\n%s\n", buff);   
                 }
                 close(status);
             }
         }
         if(!strcmp(params[0],"cd"))
         {
             status1=chdir(directory); 
             if(status1 !=0)
                 perror("Eroare!");
         }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do a bt in gdb after a crash you'll see where exactly it blew its load.  Might get you closer to the root cause.  Can also generally open .core files.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
char *file_name;

// ...

gets(file_name);
```

attempt to read data using an *uninitialised pointer*, and this can cause a segfault reading the keyboard into an undefined buffer, when you press Enter, before you even try to open the file. Furthermore, the use of `gets()` is deprecated. Strangely, you do know about `fgets()` and the trailing `newline`.

Answer (score 0):

Just import open. If you use "with open __ " then you can read the file. Depending on which type of read you want to use. For binary, you can use "rb", but "r" will also work. Default is "wb" actually.

Answer (score 0):

to find where is your error you can use valgrind:

```
gcc -g stack.c
valgrind ./a.out
```

This show you that your program segfault at the line 86

```
==3384== Invalid read of size 1
==3384==    at 0x4C2F1B1: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3384==    by 0x400C52: main (stack.c:86)
==3384==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

This error happen only when there is no parameter for your "uniq" command.

```
antoine@shell >>
antoine@shell >>
antoine@shell >>uniq stack.c
antoine@shell >>uniq
[1]    4154 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

because in this case param[1] is uninitialized:

```
    if(!strcmp(params[1],"-d"))
```

A solution is to make your parseCmd return  the number of parameters detected and check if the result is == 2 (uniq myFile).